# Error: libdjvu/miniexp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm

I try install python-djvulibre and have this error - " libdjvu/miniexp.h: No such file or directory" but DjVuLibre is installed and in folder exists this file
Log:

```
build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\src\decode.c(697): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: libdjvu/miniexp.h: No such file or directory,
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-djvulibre
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-djvulibre, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: it seems it needs to compiler C/C++ code and it needs DjVuLibre source code with files `*.h`. And this is NOT part of Python so you have to manually download and install it. See `Source packages` on http://djvu.sourceforge.net/

Comment: how can pycharm point to these sources? they are not visible during installation

Comment: PyCharm has nothing to do with this - you have to manually download it from [djvu.sourceforge.net](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/), and manually install it (uncompress it), and manually add path to this resource. I don't know where to add path. I use Linux and I can automotically install this C/C++ library.